# CASE expression in MySQL not evaluating

Tags: mysql, case

I have a CASE expression in one of MySQL queries that checks for the lesser or earlier of the two dates, however I am having problem getting it to work properly

```
update SaveContactForm7_1
SET `TStat` = 
CASE
    WHEN 
        (`DateP1` IS NOT NULL OR `DateP2` IS NOT NULL) 
        AND `T1A` BETWEEN (`Date`-1 AND (`DateP1` OR `DateP2`)) 
        AND `T1A` < `SLH` 
        AND `T2A` IS NULL
        AND `T3A` IS NULL 
    THEN 'T1'
    WHEN
       (`DateP1` IS NOT NULL OR `DateP2` IS NOT NULL) 
        AND `T2A` BETWEEN (`Date`-1 AND (`DateP1` OR `DateP2`)) 
         AND `T2A` < `SLH` 
        AND `T3A` IS NULL 
    THEN 'T2'
END;
```

It always to evaluates to T1 or T2 or skips the `T1A` < `SLH` evaluation altogether. I have tried placing in braces (`T1A`<`SLH`) but that doesn't work either.

```
select * from SaveContactForm7_1 where `T1A`>`SLH` and TStat='T1';
```

and it shows all the rows that "escaped" the update query. `DateP1`, `DateP2`, `Date`, `T1A`, `T2A`... are all date types. How can I write the update query so that the `T1A` < `SLH` is evaluated. Can you please advise?

Comment: give an example of row that should (in your opinion) evaluate to T1 or T2

Comment: "....checks for the lesser or earlier of the two dates". I knew that the problem was due to the way I had written all the nests and not due to the actual query not evaluating to T1 or T2. Why the downvote? Please reconsider undoing the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not do what you expect :

```
AND `T1A` BETWEEN (`Date`-1 AND (`DateP1` OR `DateP2`))
```

I guess that you want this instead :

```
AND `T1A` BETWEEN (`Date`-1 AND COALESCE(`DateP1` `DateP2`))
```

Comment: Thanks GMB. I was able to get the desired result using your solution.